# upload files with dropzone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js in my Node.js  application and want to retrieve uploaded file from the query :

This is my angular code :

```
 var myapp=angular.module('myapp',['dropZone'])         
 angular.module('dropZone', [])
    .directive('dropZone', function() 
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.dropzone({
                url: "/upload",
                maxFilesize: 100,
                paramName: "file",
                maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
                init: function() {
                    scope.files.push({file: 'added'}); // here works
                    this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                    });

                    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                        scope.$apply(function(){
                            alert(file);
                            scope.files.push({file: 'added'});
                        });
                    });

                    this.on('drop', function(file) {
                        alert('file');
                    });


                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Server code  :

```
router.post('/upload',function (req,res) {
      console.log(req.body.file);
      // it shows  "undefined"

      });
```

my form is sent to the server but  req.body.file is empty, and I can't send data (within hidden input) either.